# Google Map Marker Arrow

Tags: javascript, html, css, dictionary

Visit this page http://bherns.com/fasttrack/contact.html. here you can see google map. This map with normal html is working fine. But when i add this map in muse it's still working fine but when i click on a location marker so in box in the bottom i can see an arrow. I am trying to look inspect element but how i can check which html element is working for this arrow. I don't need this arrow. [CSS File](http://bherns.com/fasttrack/css/site_global.css) This is css file. When i remove this css file this arrow is not showing but then other elements are not working properly definitely. So please can you tell me the solution. Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

change top:112px; to **top:90px;** in your **code**

[image]